# User can access stored procedure, but not the underlying code directly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to create a stored procedure `SP1` which will have script to fetch data from `sys` schema. But this stored procedure would be called by users who do not have permissions on the `sys` schema. How can I achieve this?

I am doing this basically to mask the entire `sys` schema from that user but at the same time allowing him to see minimal info.

Basically I want this inside SP

```
--Displays Object information
SELECT m.object_id [ObjID]
       ,o.type_desc [ObjType]
       ,o.name [ObjectName]
       ,e.last_execution_time [LastExecutedOn]
       ,create_date [CreatedOn]
       ,modify_date [ModifiedOn]
       , DEFINITION [Data]
FROM sys.SQL_MODULES m
JOIN sys.OBJECTS o
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats e
ON e.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE DEFINITION LIKE '%'+@SearchStr+'%'
ORDER BY o.name
```

Comment: What happens if you grant execute access to the SP and nothing more?

Comment: SP is accessible to that user. But when he runs it he gets error msg saying you do not have permission to access sys objects.

Basically I want this inside SP


--Displays Object information
SELECT m.object_id [ObjID]
  ,o.type_desc [ObjType]
  ,o.name [ObjectName]
  ,e.last_execution_time [LastExecutedOn]
  ,create_date [CreatedOn]
  ,modify_date [ModifiedOn]
  , DEFINITION [Data]
FROM sys.SQL_MODULES m
JOIN sys.OBJECTS o
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats e
ON e.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE DEFINITION LIKE '%'+@SearchStr+'%'
ORDER BY o.name

Comment: ... why are you doing this?  What larger-picture problem are you trying to solve?  What are you trying to protect against?  Generally `sys` is the domain of admin/developers - for anybody else, they wouldn't need to see it at all.  If somebody has read access on the rest of the DB, they can get most of the DB layout anyways.... and the data in the regular tables is usually far more valuable than the layout records.  You're probably looking for [`EXECUTE AS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354(v=sql.100).aspx), although I'm not certain of all the ramifications.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could achieve this with a View rather than an SP, as per [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89632/sql-server-grant-select-access-to-a-user-in-a-view-and-not-in-its-tables) question.

If you need to be able to pass a parameter as well for your `@SearchStr` variable, you could create an SP which queries the view accordingly. So your View would be:

```
CREATE VIEW vwObjectInfo
AS
    SELECT m.OBJECT_ID [ObjID],
           o.type_desc [ObjType],
           o.name [ObjectName],
           e.last_execution_time [LastExecutedOn],
           create_date [CreatedOn],
           modify_date [ModifiedOn],
           [definition] [Data]
    FROM sys.SQL_MODULES m
    JOIN sys.OBJECTS o ON m.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats e ON e.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID
```

and your SP would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSearchObjectInfo
    @SearchStr NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM vwObjectInfo 
    WHERE Data LIKE '%' + @SearchStr + '%' 
    ORDER BY ObjectName
END
```

Your user should then be able to call the SP with their desired search string and get results with just the ability to SELECT from the View and EXECUTE the SP, like so:

```
EXEC spSearchObjectInfo 'Some Search String'
```